# Partial thread synchronisation

Tags: cuda

In my application I have divided the work so that each warp do one work-unit.

In order to start the work on the unit, thread zero of each block have to calculate a recurrence relation from constant `C0` up to `CW` where `W= #warp - 1`.

Conceptually it looks like this:

```
if(threadId.x ==0) {
    for(x=1;x<#warps;x++) {
        C[x] = calc_recur(C[x-1]);
    }
}
syncthreads();
```

What I want to do is to release the threads early when the recurrence relation for each warp have been calculated.

It would look something like this:

```
for(x=1;x<#warps;x++) {
    if(threadId.x ==0) {
        C[x] = calc_recur(C[x-1]);
    }
    if(x < warpId) {
        partial_syncthreads(x);
    }
}
```

where partial_syncthreads would sync all the threads that belong to an warp greater than x.

Is there any algorithm that would enable this?

Comment: At first: Why do you want to do this? `syncthreads()` does only ensure, that all threads are finished with their previous work. I can't see a reason, why you want to synchronize them in every loop. The second point: Do you, maybe, mix the terms `block` and `warp`?

Comment: Why I want to do this: If possible, it would create a makeshift pipeline of work, by allowing warps to begin their work earlier, it will also finish working earlier, only to be filled by another work later on. As my work on each work unit makes heavy use of random access, I request way to many cachlines, so in order to stage some work earlier it would be possible to relieve some pressure of the memory bus.

The reason I would synchronize them each loop is so that they can not escape before their work unit is calculated.

No, the threads in the warp less than x have their work unit calculated.

Comment: Ok. I got your point. Netherless, I think you should replace the term "synchronization" (which only ensures, that every thread is at the point of calling of this function) with something like "release". What stops you from stopping you kernel, calculating `C[x]` in a small kernel and then running a bigger kernel again (or what you want to do next)? This would release all unneeded threads until you start the next kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure, but I doubt, that there is a way to reduce the number of threads at the runtime of a kernel.

Because of this, I would propose, to

(1) leave it, as it is. Synchronizing threads make no sense at this point.

(2) split your kernel to multiple kernels. So that your shown code is calculated by a reduced number of threads. But with this method, you won't have access to shared memory.

(3) perform the calculation on the host. Since it is a highly serial implementation, this could be the faster way. Here you have to be sure, that your function `calc_recur()` is expensive enough, that the transfer to the host, doesn't negate the speed benefits.